# How can I retrieve the image I put in RadImageEditor using Telerik

Tags: c#, image, telerik

So I was using Telerik Framework and this is what is used when opening Image and pass to `RadImageEditor`. But my problem is that when I finished editing, I want to pass again the image to the `PictureBox` and not save it to the Local.

What I used for passing the `Image` to `RadImageEditor` is this:

`radImageEditor1.OpenImage((Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Bitmap)));`

Is there anyone who help me? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The save button on the toolbar fires an event that will give you the current image. You can invoke that with the client side API too

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is in the args passed by the RadImageEditor *ImageSaving* event. However you must be carefull because it will return a property called "Image" that induct to guess that it is the image itself, while it is just a class that owns the image (as well other data such as its width, height, etc). It took me a while to figure it out.

So in the following code:

```
Protected Sub RadImageEditor1_ImageSaving(sender As Object, e As ImageEditorSavingEventArgs)
    Dim imgw As Integer = e.Image.Width
    Dim imgh As Integer = e.Image.Height

    Dim theimage As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(e.Image.Image, imgw, imgh)

    Dim stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream
    theimage.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    stream.Position = 0
    Dim Image(stream.Length) As Byte
    stream.Read(Image, 0, stream.Length)
End Sub
```

Notice in the third line of the function the image parameter is not in e.Image but in **e.Image.Image**.